# Redirect in certain hours .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like the traffic on `site1.com` to be redirected to `site2.com` only from 1pm to 2pm and from 11pm to 5am.

This redirect only if users are from Italy.

Is it possible?

I've tried something like this... but it does not work properly.

```
Order deny,allow
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0600
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1800 
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ page.day.html 
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ page.night.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to consider here:

1. Your rewrite conditions only apply to one rewrite rule
2. you could tie your redirects to certain IP ranges that are known to come from Italy but this isn't very reliable. Consider a code level solution for the location aspect instead. But know that it will never be perfect.
3. There is no need to use `%{TIME_MIN}` if you're only interested in hours

All that taken into consideration, I would try something like this:

```
Order deny,allow
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >13
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <14
RewriteRule (.*) http://site2.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >23 
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <5
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Note that I am forcing a 302 redirect (moved temporarily) to indicate that the redirect is not permanent.